# Issue with forked GitHub repo which contains submodule folder

Tags: git, github, git-submodules, git-fork

1. In my **Project1** I am using this library "https://github.com/ValeriiKov/realm-js".

in "*package.json*" it looks like:

```
...
"realm": "2.28.1",
...
```

2. Then I forked this "realm-js" wuth --recurse-submodules option. 
   (also tried "git submodule update --init" in forked (ValeriiKov/realm-js) repo).

After this "*package.json*" looks like:

```
...
"realm": "https://github.com/ValeriiKov/realm-js#v2.28.1",
...
```

but "realm-js" contain submodule (vendor/GCDWebServer)

[image]

and when I delete "node_modules" in **Project1** and run *yarn* the submodule folder is empty! 
.../node_modules/realm/vendor/GCDWebServer

and therefore I cannot build **Project1**.

My question is why 
.../node_modules/realm/vendor/GCDWebServer
is empty after I forked realm-js (with --recurse-submodules) and added a link to forked realm-js in "*package.json*" of my **Project1**?

Comment: Have you initialized the submodule yet or cloned with `--recurse-submodules`? If not, it will be empty until you run something like `git submodule update --init`.

Comment: @bk2204 I've updated my post. Yes, I tried clone with "--recurse-submodules" as well as  "git submodule update --init" after cloning. But the same result - GCDWebServer is empty in Project1 (and with content in forked /ValeriiKov/realm-js)